# text change event on text box using binding source

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have a `Textbox` in Windows form and i want to do some calculation when user enter value . But Problem is that when my form load the `Textbox_TextChange` event fire because binding source fill 0 in the text box. So How can i do that  .

Many thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your problem... You need to get your calculations done, why does it matter if initial value is 0? Aren't you going to change it? Please, post some code.

Answer (score 0):

One way is adding a boolean field and set it to true:

```
class Form1{
    bool firstTime = true;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then in your `Textbox_TextChange` method, only do the calculations when `firstTime` is `false`:

```
void Textbox_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!firstTime)
    {
        //do calculations
    }
    firstTime = false;
}
```

So when you do the binding, which is the first time the text changes, the calculations won't be executed.

Comment: but problem is that when form load binding source fill all values so that time how can i manage that